# Python - plotting large number of lines

Tags: python, performance, matplotlib

I am trying to read in a file containing XY endpoints of line segments and a value associated with the segment, then plot the line segments colored by the value given.  The problem I am having is that there is potentially hundreds of thousands to millions of line segments and when I attempt to read in these larger files I run into a memory error.  Is there a more memory efficient way of doing this?

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.colors as colors
import matplotlib.cm as cmx
import sys
import csv

if len(sys.argv) > 1:
    flofile = sys.argv[1]
else:
    flofile = "GU3\GU3.flo"

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
jet = cm = plt.get_cmap('jet')
cNorm = colors.Normalize(vmin=0)
scalarMap = cmx.ScalarMappable(norm=cNorm,cmap=jet)
with open(flofile) as FLO:
    title = FLO.readline()
    limits = [float(tp) for tp in FLO.readline().split()]
    FLO.readline()#headers
    for line in FLO:
        if 'WELLS' in line: break        
        frac = ([float(tp) for tp in line.split()])
        ax.plot([frac[0],frac[2]],[frac[1],frac[3]],color=colorVal)


#ax.plot(*call_list)
scalarMap._A = []
plt.colorbar(scalarMap)
plt.xlim([0,limits[0]])
plt.ylim([0,limits[1]])

plt.show()
```

This code works for small files.  Thanks.

Comment: What do you hope to see? Either your image is humongous so you can distinguish millions of line segments, or your million of line segments overlap on a reasonably sized image. Can you reduce the extent of you problem by calculating something akin to a density, reducing millions of line segments to maybe a few hundred or a few thousand data points?

Comment: Here is an example of what I am hoping to generate: [link](http://s10.postimg.org/gihylk9ih/Fracout_0000.png), this example has over 100,000 line segments.  I really can't reduce to a density as the lines orientation and how it connects to the other lines can affect the values as much as spacial location.  I have an outdated Fortran/C++/OpenGL code that does this, I was just hoping to update, and potentially add a GUI onto the program.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I would look into `LineCollection` [(doc)](http://matplotlib.org/api/collections_api.html#matplotlib.collections.LineCollection).

```
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt    
import random


s = (600,400)
N = 100000

segs = []
colors = []
my_cmap = plt.get_cmap('jet')
for i in range(N):
    x1 = random.random() * s[0]
    y1 = random.random() * s[1]
    x2 = random.random() * s[0]
    y2 = random.random() * s[1]
    c  = random.random()
    colors.append(my_cmap(c))
    segs.append(((x1, y1), (x2, y2)))

ln_coll = matplotlib.collections.LineCollection(segs, colors=colors)

ax = plt.gca()
ax.add_collection(ln_coll)
ax.set_xlim(0, 600)    
ax.set_ylim(0, 400)
plt.draw()
```

It wil also take a list of numpy arrays for the first arguement.

Comment: Thanks for this, I had looked at LineCollection before but didn't get the color changes without making multiple linecollections, which ended up with the same memory error.  Your solution worked perfectly though.

Comment: @user2236411 glad it helped.  Welcome to SO!

Answer (score 5):

You might consider doing the plotting on a bitmap image first, which doesn't have the memory problem, and after that fine tune the plot/image with matplotlib. As an example:

```
from PIL import Image
from PIL import ImageDraw
import random
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.image as mpimg

s = (500,500)
N = 100000

im = Image.new('RGBA', s, (255,255,255,255))
draw = ImageDraw.Draw(im)

for i in range(N):
    x1 = random.random() * s[0]
    y1 = random.random() * s[1]
    x2 = random.random() * s[0]
    y2 = random.random() * s[1]
    c  = random.random() * 256
    draw.line(((x1,y1),(x2,y2)), fill=(0, 255 - int(c), int(c), 255), width=1)

plt.imshow(np.asarray(im), extent=(-1,1,-1,1), aspect='equal', origin='lower')
plt.show()
```

Comment: Thank you for this solution, I ended up using LineCollection instead as it fit my need better, but this solution would have worked as well.  However, if anyone uses this solution, I believe the bitmap image moves the origin to the top left, rather than the bottom left with a plot; so you will need to translate the y value or your image will be mirrored about the x-axis.

Comment: @user2236411 You're right, the image is mirrored over the x-axis, this could be fixed with the keyword argument 'origin' of `imshow`. I fixed and edited the script for this and some other things (the im.save and mpimg.imread were not necessary). The solution of tcaswell is better because it uses only one coordinate system and only matplotlib.

Comment: this is a very good approach for large data and orders of magnitude faster than anything else